# How to iterate through a folder that contains csv files, extract each file's modified date and create a new column as " modified date" using Python

Tags: python, csv

Did some research and found the python code below that is be able to extract the modified date of a csv file. Help needed on how to write python code to iterate through a folder that contains multiple csv files. For each file, the extracted modified date will be added as new column as "date" in each of the csv file in the folder.

Python code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from os.path import getmtime

file = 'abc.csv'
datetime.fromtimestamp(getmtime(file)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

output answer :
'01/15/2020'
```

Comment: Do you want to add another column to the file based on the output answer you have provided? say there are 100 rows, would you then add the date into the date column 100 times?

Comment: hi Sir, yes . the idea is, if i have 10 csv files within a folder, each file let's say has 100 rows, each file will have a new column name calls 'date' and the new column will be filled with the csv file's modified date. Hope i explain it clearly. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can call on each csv filename. You can walk the directory in a for loop and call this function each time.

### Description:

Add a new column `date` to a csv `file` with the value of `dateCreated`

### The params:

1. `file` : file name of the csv being edited
2. `dateCreated` : variable you have computed in the example

### Returns:

None

```py
import csv

def addDate(file,dateCreated):
  # Open a file and a temp file
  temp = "temp.csv"
  with open(file) as f, open(temp, "w") as o:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    w = csv.writer(o)

    # Set the column name to date
    header = next(rows)
    header.append("date")
    w.write(header)
    #iterate over the rows and add the date
    for row in rows:
      row.append(dateCreated)
      w.write(row)
  os.rename(temp, file)
```